# sharing object between proxy in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I create several proxys with vfs transport. I also use class mediator in each proxy. 
My question is : Is it possible in WSO2 ESB to share an object between proxy and also between class mediator? 

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can set the object into a [property](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Property+Mediator) in synapse scope (or default) and use it in both the class mediator and the proxy. In the class mediator you can get the property value as `messageContext.getProperty(NAME);` and set it as `messageContext.setProperty(NAME, VALUE);`

Comment: can I pass that property to other proxy?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. The property will be limited to the respective message (request) where it was set.